# Have Leaflet marker popup open on page load

Tags: javascript

Has anyone used Leaflet to display a single location, while making the "popup" open when the map is loaded?  This is really easy to do in Leaflet, but the module's JS is a little hard to decipher.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The leaflet module fires an event after a map is created, called "leaflet.map".
You should be able to listen for this event and get the map object like this:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.openMarker = {
    attach:function (context, settings) {
      $(document, context).on('leaflet.map', function(event, map){
        // console.log(map);
        // logic to open marker goes here
      })
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Leaflet module also fires an event called 'leaflet.feature'.

NOTE: the above code is untested

Comment: Thank you, 2pha. This seems logical, however, I can't get it to work. Once uncommented, `console.log(map)` doesn't output anything. Even if I change the output to a string, I get nothing.

Comment: does the event function work at all?

Comment: No, it doesn't. In addition to trying what you have above, I changed a couple things http://www.codeshare.io/NzkP8. Still not working.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure sorry. I just looked at the js for the Leaflet module and saw that it was meant to fire a leaflet.map event. I do not have a drupal install with leaflet atm.

Comment: thanks for your help so far. It pushed me in the right direction. Would mind looking at what I have working at this point? http://www.codeshare.io/NzkP8 I feel really close, but I simply don't understand the logic well enough. I've spent more time than I should have for this, "should be simple" feature.

Comment: Drupal behaviors are fired when the page is fully loaded (called in a global document.ready) and when ajax calls are returned. No need to put $(window).on('load'). Your code looks ok but I don't have a site with leaflet to test on and I no longer use leaflet as I have created my own branch (which implements my patch at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2089209)

Answer (score 0):

@2pha solution proves that, this might work, I've got map object, but no methods there. I think better is to search in settings.leaflet.mymap.lMap - there is the openPopup method. You just have to find marker to open popup on it, even with jQuery selector.

But you can also use poorman's solution, just click on existing markers:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.customLeafletPopup = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        var existCondition = setInterval(function() {
          if ($('.leaflet-marker-icon').length) {
             clearInterval(existCondition);
             $('.leaflet-marker-icon').each(function () {
              setTimeout($(this).click(), 5000);
            });
          }
         }, 1000); // check every 1000ms
      
      }
    };
  })(jQuery);
```